# Всегда ли нужно указывать миллион позиций у элементов?

Tags: вёрстка

при верстке пиксель пёрфект (также и с ошибками в несколько пикселей), будучи новичком, у меня возник вопрос: чтобы позиционировать нужный элемент (ну например некий спан с текстом, и таких спанов может быть 500) нужно указать ему имя, далее position absolute, отмерять ему пиксели (даже если делать на глаз то нужно все равно морочиться) и т.д.? А не слишком ли это долго? То есть таких элементов может быть и несколько тысяч на нескольких страницах. Я пока что успел только изучить позиционирование от левого верхнего края родительского элемента, и мне достаточно указать лишь left-top для позиционирования. Есть ли другие способы (более быстрые!) позиционирования этих сотен элементов?

Comment: position absolute не работает. просто прими это. как  факт. при отображении на разных расширениях у тебя все поедет.. и пиксельпефекта не будет.

Comment: Pixel perfect не нужен в 99.9999% случаев.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко есть указание left-top в процентах, что я и использую

Comment: @AlexeyTen в любом случае нужно именовать каждый span, и указывать для него left-top. Есть ли другой способ, где не нужно именовать span, но при этом суметь спозиционировать нужный мне span куда нужно?

Comment: Зачем? Вы каждое слово отдельно что ли позиционируете?

Comment: @AlexeyTen каждый параграф))

Comment: наверняка нстьткакой то принип размещения (формула)